# Html table overlap with next cell

Tags: html, css, html-table, grid

Html table with in td cell have select option. When increase select box width, it will need to auto overlap next cells.

How to do this.

[image]

Comment: `colspan` google it, you'll get your answer.

Comment: @AbhishekPandey thanks for replay,  but i need behind cell also for some reason

Comment: try css word-wrap: break-word;

Comment: @paranjothi, Do you need like this: https://plnkr.co/edit/MGL3miJcxbaizEGhc1Xp?p=preview

Comment: @Ahmed not like this

Comment: Don't you need the select option?

Comment: Can you post your code, then we can work with it to provide the solution. Without your original code, any answer posted would be just a guess, as useless as [this](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/6xzre9y7/).